# Dell Inspiron can no longer pick up my wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron (not 100% sure what the correct version number is; the sticker on it says 15R but PC info says 5537). It's running the 64-bit version of Windows 8.1.

Today it's lost the ability to pick up my home wifi network. I can see the neighbours' networks in the networks menu, but not mine. Two other devices can still see and connect to my network, so it's definitely the laptop that's the problem.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this please? So far I have:

-Restarted the laptop (an actual restart as well as shutting it down and turning it on)

-Switched off the router at the plug and switched it back on again

-Confirmed that WLAN AutoConfig is running and its startup type is set to automatic

-Wireless Adapter Settings are set to maximum performance in my power plan

-Set my network adapter's roaming aggressiveness to the highest setting

If it helps, my network adapter is Intel(R) Wireless-N 7260 and the driver is version 17.0.6.1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: HERE IS YOU SUPPORT PAGE IF YOU NEED DRIVERS, MANUALS OR DIAGNOSTICS TOOLS,  select your OS first>>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15r-5537/drivers

Comment: I can see the neighbours' networks in the networks menu, but not mine   ......   Try updating the firmware in your router.

Comment: Sometimes Windows has an issue with the list of WiFi connections. See https://www.wikihow.com/Manually-Reset-Your-Wireless-Adapter-in-Windows about resetting the adapter. Another way to confirm it's the OS fault: run another OS, e.g. Linux, from USB (no need to install on PC). See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, for example.

Comment: @John How do I update the firmware in my router and what are the consequences (does it change the router name, password etc)?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I have disabled and enabled the adapter with no success. Before I reset all network adapters (method 2 on the wikihow link), what are the consequences of this? If I delete my wireless adapter and this doesn't fix the problem, surely I'll then be left unable to get the adapter back as no internet connection?

Comment: Also, I have just discovered that another device is having the same problem. It's a Lenovo running Windows 10 64 bit. Really weird as another Windows 10 device can pick up the network ok! I also don't know if it's relevant that the two problem devices are the oldest ones in the house (8 and 9 years old respectively). Does this help diagnosis at all?

Comment: How do I update the firmware in my router and what are the consequences (does it change the router name, password etc)   .... Depends on the router. First, user and password normally survives firmware update. Look up your model on the makers website and get the firmware there, download it then use the firmware update function on your router.